# Finding matching selector element within jQuery.on()

Tags: jquery, html, events, css-selectors

Let's say that I have some HTML markup that looks like this:

```
<a href='#!' class='foo'><i class='bar'></i> Link</a>
```

And then, say, I am binding a jQuery event handler to my document like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.foo','click',function(e) {
  var obj = e.target;
  console.log(obj);
});
```

If I click on the text in the anchor ("Link"), "obj" ends up being set to the "a.foo" element.  However, when I click on the icon within the link, "obj" ends up being set to the "i.bar" element.

I've added code to find the appropriate element like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.foo','click',function(e) {
  var obj = e.target;
  if (!$(obj).hasClass('foo')) {
    obj = $(obj).parents('.foo').first();
  }
  console.log(obj);
});
```

I'm just wondering if there isn't a more elegant solution.  For instance, it would be nice if you could call "e.selectorTarget" or something and it would return that item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.on()` call is using the delegated event syntax with the `'.foo'` selector specified, so jQuery will set `this` to the `.foo` element.

```
$(document).on('click','.foo','click',function(e) {
    console.log(this);
});
```

As explained by [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> *When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching [the specified] `selector`. (Note that this may not be equal to `event.target` if the event has bubbled from a descendant element.)*

Note that specifying `'click'` in the third (data) parameter of `.on()` is kind of redundant. If you will be calling the same function for more than one type of event you can get the type using the [`event.type` property](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/).

Comment: Haha...  wow!  I guess I forgot to try the most obvious solution.  I'm embarrassed to say that I've actually been frustrated for this for some time.  How in the world did I never try "this"?

Answer (score 1):

### event.currentTarget

Use [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) to refer to the element handling the event (in this case `.foo`), even when `this` might not.

According to the jQuery documentation:

> *If you are using jQuery.proxy or another form of scope manipulation,*
> `this` *will be equal to whatever context you have provided, not*
> `event.currentTarget`

What this means is that if a proxy is used, `this` will refer to the object provided as a proxy, so `event.currentTarget` is the guaranteed way to get the element handling the event.

#### Also Of Note

You can also use [`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) to refer to the element to which the event was delegated (in this case `document` since you're using `$(document).on()`).

### Working Example

Here is a fiddle showing the differences between the targets and this: http://jsfiddle.net/2s2CE/